# Ng-repeat of Objects in Array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Array of Objects retrieved from server. The Query works, but when I do the `ng-repeat` in the html view, it doesn't work, it doesn't show anything. Why?
This is the js code:

```
$scope.companyList = [];

$scope.getCompanyList = function() {
    $scope.companyList.length = 0;

    CompanyListSrv.getCompanyListDetail(function (companyListDetail) {
        if (companyListDetail) {
            $scope.companyList = companyListDetail;
        }
    });
};

$scope.getCompanyList();
```

HTML code:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="company in companyList">
     <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ company.email }}</td> 
   </tr>
```

This is the companyListDetail Array (response from server):

```
companyListDetail: Array[2]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  length: 2
```

This is the `0: Object` :

```
email: "text@text.com"
name: "Compant 2"
```

In console I have no error, and in html page of browser I have this:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: company in companyList -->
```

Comment: Cant see obvios errors. Try check next:

1. How do you use async call? Using $http?  Try to put  

$timeout(function(){$scope.companyList = companyListDetail;}) ;

2. Put 

console.log(companyListDetail)  

just after function (companyListDetail) {

Comment: Put console.log($scope.companyList) after calling the function $scope.getCompanyList() and check whether the data is available or not. The problem may be data (**companyList**) is not available for ng-repeat

Comment: check `$scope.companyList = companyListDetail;` by `console.log($scope.companyList)` as it is having same array of objects or not.

Comment: @Vitalii I can see the this log: [Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object

Comment: @DineshSundaraneedi I think you found the problem, because if I write         console.log($scope.companyList); before to close the getCompanyList function, this is the log:    [ ]

Comment: @RohitJindal if I write console.log($scope.companyList) after $scope.companyList=companyListDetail the console shows the array correctly. But if I write it at the end - before to close the getCompanyList function - console returns an empty array

Comment: I've solved writing '$scope.$apply()'

Comment: But using $apply() some times give you error because values which are bind to DOM  will be watched by default. Better check with $http call whether you doing it properly or not.
Can you share the service code @panagulis72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.companyList.length = 0; // This line is good, it empties the array without modifying the reference

CompanyListSrv.getCompanyListDetail(function (companyListDetail) {
    if (companyListDetail) {
        $scope.companyList = companyListDetail; // this line is bad, you assign $scope.companyList to a new reference
    } 
});
```

The issue here, is that angular $watch mechanism checks if the object has changed but has only remembered his first reference.

The reason why `console.log()` works is because you give this function the new reference of your object.

what you can do is the following :

```
if (companyListDetail) {
     for (var i = 0; i< companyListDetail; i++){
         $scope.companyList.push(companyListDetail[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: It's watched as `$scope`s property. I guess simple `$scope.$apply()` will fix it.

Comment: @vp_arth $scope.$apply() will work but will trigger a complete check of all $watches of the app. It lowers the perfs, and can potentially throw an exception if an apply was already in progress. You should never use $apply!

Comment: Deblaton thank you, but it doesn't work yet... I think that it's because I'm doing asyn calling, because I'm using couchdb

Comment: an async call should return a promise.

Comment: So I will return two elements, companyListDetail and the Promise?

Comment: the promise should contain the companyListDetail

Comment: `"You should never use $apply"` but it is only one way to update scope. `$timeout`/`$http`/etc services all called it at the end of async call.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe about performances, is better to user your way (push the companyListDetail using a for loop) or create a new reference?

Comment: It does not create a new reference. It assigns the already created reference of companyListDetail to $scope.companyList. the $scope.$apply costs way more than creating a reference.

Comment: I've tried in your way, with the promises, but I can't say to angular 'ng-repeat JUST AFTER the query'

Comment: you don't have to, you just have to update correctly your collections, and angular will trigger it for you.

Comment: @panagulis72 Thank you for accepting my answer. Although, I don't understand what improved. Maybe you made another mistake (with promises), and in that case, you could have written your own answer. The aim of this site is to provide answers for other people. I'm not sure we meet this requirement here.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe in fact I've not found a final solution, but you helped me a lot especially to understand where the problem was. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

You forgot to add `<table>` tag in `Html`.

**Html :**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="company in companyList">
     <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ company.email }}</td> 
   </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

**Script :**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.companyList = [];

$scope.getCompanyList = function() {
    $scope.companyList.length = 0;
    var companyListDetail = [{
  email: "sidhantc@google.com",
  name: "Sidhant"
  },
  {
  email: "sid@google.com",
  name: "Chopper"
  }]

            $scope.companyList = companyListDetail;
            console.log($scope.companyList);
};

$scope.getCompanyList();
}
```

Working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2864/

Comment: In my html I wrote <table> correctly, I've just picked a piece of my code! The real problem is that there are async call